# Internal link to menu item not working

Tags: 7

I have several rows with elements and I created the delete operation for each row. When I clicked the delete link, nothing happens (it seems that don't calling the delete function).

Code of the menu item (delete function):

```
$items['node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/factors/%factor_component/delete'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('forms_grade_factors_delete_factor', 1, 4),
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

Code of the deletion function:

```
function forms_grade_factors_delete_factor($form_state, $node, $component) {
    $form = array();
    $form['node'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $node,
    );
    $form['component'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $component,
    );
    $question = t('Are you sure you want to delete this component?');
    $description = t('Description');
    return confirm_form($form, $question, 'node/'.$node.'/webform/components');
}
```

Code of the table (with the deletion links):

```
foreach($all_factors as $factor) {
  $delete_link = l(t('Delete'), '/node/'.$nid.'/webform-factors/factors/'.$factor->fid.'/delete',
                                  array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
  $factors[] = array($factor->factor_name, $factor->factor_formula, $delete_link);
}
$form['factors'] = array(
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => array(t('Factor'), t('Formula'), t('Operations')),
  '#rows' => $factors,
);
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Have you cleared the drupal cache after adding new menu item? What happens when you click on the link, does it take you to access denied page or any other, do you see any error message.

Comment: Hi arpitr! Yes, I cleared the cache and desactivated/activated the module. When I clicked the link, nothing happens (just the current page reloads). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I forgot to clarify, when I click on the link, don't show any denied page or error message. Only the current page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the your form callback, seems like you are missing argument $form. Small Change as following

From:

```
function forms_grade_factors_delete_factor($form_state, $node, $component) {
```

To:

```
function forms_grade_factors_delete_factor($form, &$form_state, $node, $component) {
```

Comment: I added the $form argument, changed &$form_state, cleared the cache, and still not working. :(

Comment: Try putting the url directly to browser

Comment: I already tried it and didn't work either. Nothing happens. `http://drupal.dev/node/12/webform-factors/factors/1/delete?destination=node/12/webform-factors`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by nothing happens, you should get error page, page not found or at least white page.

Comment: If you are around, you can join chat-room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29006/internal-link-to-menu-item-not-working